# Make html+css layot for posts

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I want to make page layot for imageboard. I am new at css and tried different solutions none of them works as I want. There should be post with pictures float to the left and text that wraps arount it. Sound pretty simple but I can't accomplish it.

I've tried to make container "post" where will be 3 of children container in their order: postHeader (which should be on top), pic (with picture) and text (with text post). 
I've tried to set pic and text display:inline-block; to make them align in one line but without text with property witdh it draws one under other. I tried set float: left on pic to make picture float left and make word wrap around it but then if text is too few there is no container sizing up. I dont want to use sizes, it breaks responsivness.

What I've tried

css:

```
.post {
    min-height: 100px;
}
.pic {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.text {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="thread">
        <div class="post op">
            <div class="postHeader">Post header</div>    
            <div class="pic">
                <div  class="picName">
                    <a class="picLink" href="content/cat_and_banana.jpg">cat_and_banana.jpg</a>
                </div>
                <img class="picThumbnail" src="content/thumbnail/123.jpg">
            </div>   
            <div class="text">Some text</div>             
        </div>
    </div>
```

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUElh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Heres a quick sample I made, hope it does what you need

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}
.bodycontainer{
 background-color: green;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.piccontainer{
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img{
 height: 180px;
 width: 200px;
 margin: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><h2>HEADER</h2></div>
  
  <div class="bodycontainer">
  <div class="piccontainer">
  <img align="left" src="https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/48/posts/27341/preview_image/html-basics-3.png"/>
  <img align="left" src="https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/48/posts/27341/preview_image/html-basics-3.png"/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum..</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```